# Pandas - Split columns into rows while keeping indices

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following simplified `DataFrame`:

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame([{'index_a':'a1', 'index_b':'b1', 'value_x':'x1', 'value_y':'y1'},
              {'index_a':'a2', 'index_b':'b2', 'value_x':'x2', 'value_y':'y2'},
              {'index_a':'a3', 'index_b':'b3', 'value_x':'x3', 'value_y':'y3'}])
```

It contains two indices and two value columns. For downstream usage, it does not make sense to have two value columns (they are from the same distribution). I therefore want to 'explode' these columns and make one large list. This is what should result:

```py
pd.DataFrame([{'index_a':'a1', 'index_b':'b1', 'value':'x1'},
              {'index_a':'a1', 'index_b':'b1', 'value':'x1'},
              {'index_a':'a2', 'index_b':'b2', 'value':'x2'},
              {'index_a':'a2', 'index_b':'b2', 'value':'y2'},
              {'index_a':'a3', 'index_b':'b3', 'value':'x3'},
              {'index_a':'a3', 'index_b':'b3', 'value':'y3'}])
```

I tried isolating values via `.value` and `.ravel()` but none yielded the desired results.

Thanks in advance. BBQuercus :)

Comment: `final=df.melt(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('index')]).drop('variable',1)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.contains()` for column names to find to filter the index columns and pass it under [`df.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) as `id_vars`:

```
final=df.melt(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('index')]).drop('variable',1)
```

---

```
  index_a index_b value
0      a1      b1    x1
1      a2      b2    x2
2      a3      b3    x3
3      a1      b1    y1
4      a2      b2    y2
5      a3      b3    y3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run the code below 
`import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'index_a':'a1', 'index_b':'b1', 'value_x':'x1', 'value_y':'y1'},
                   {'index_a':'a2', 'index_b':'b2', 'value_x':'x2', 'value_y':'y2'},
                   {'index_a':'a3', 'index_b':'b3', 'value_x':'x3', 'value_y':'y3'}])`

The result will be 
 
`index_a   index_b   value_x   value_y
0     a1          b1      x1        y1
1     a2          b2      x2        y2
2     a3          b3      x3        y3`

 
So here you can select columns `['index_a', 'index_b', 'value_x']` 
 
`df1 = df[['index_a', 'index_b', 'value_x']]`

`index_a  index_b  value_x
0   a1       b1       x1
1   a2       b2       x2
2   a3       b3       x3`

Similarly select columns `['index_a', 'index_b', 'value_y']`

`df2 = df[['index_a', 'index_b', 'value_y']]`

`index_a  index_b  value_y
0   a1       b1       y1
1   a2       b2       y2
2   a3       b3       y3`

Rename the columns `value_x` and `value_y` a common name `value`

`df1 = df1.rename(columns={'value_x' : 'value'}) <br>
 df2 = df2.rename(columns={'value_y': 'value'})`

Now concatenate the both DataFrames `df1` and `df2` ignoring index value

`df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)`

`index_a  index_b  value
0   a1       b1       x1
1   a2       b2       x2
2   a3       b3       x3
3   a1       b1       y1
4   a2       b2       y2
5   a3       b3       y3`

Sort the rows by grouping columns `index_a` and `index_b`

`df3.sort_values(['index_a', 'index_b'])`